# What ticker symbol to use for the crude oil price?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-finance

Which ticker symbol can I use for the crude oil price for the `GOOGLEFINANCE` function?

Nasdaq Brent oil is "BZ:NMX"

https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/commodities/bz:nmx

Nasdaq Crude oil is "CL:NMX"

https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/commodities/cl:nmx

I've tried these but `#N/A` is displayed

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("BZ:NMX")
=GOOGLEFINANCE("CL:NMX")
```

I also tried CL and BZ but they aren't crude oil, they are companies

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:BZ")
=GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:CL")
```

NASDAQ:BZ = Kanzhun Ltd

NASDAQ:CL = Colgate Palmolive

I also tried NASDAQ:CRUD

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:CRUD")
```

Which looks correct "WisdomTree WTI Crude Oil ETC"

But the result is 11.90 when the BZ:NMX is 119.51 (as at 8-June-2022)

Just for the record - I'm not a trader, I wanted to get historical prices of crude oil and compare the rise/fall to petrol prices at the pump

UPDATE:

There's a list of exchanges here

https://www.google.com/googlefinance/disclaimer/

I think its the NYMEX that I need to use but still getting `#N/A`

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("NYMEX:CL")
=GOOGLEFINANCE("NYMEX:CL=F")
=GOOGLEFINANCE("NYMEX:BZ=F")
=GOOGLEFINANCE("NYMEX:CL.1")
```

There's an answer here which uses `YAHOOFINANCE` - its an add on (via extensions) but wants to access a lot of information so I haven't installed it

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67478867/wti-price-in-google-sheets

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

The correct formula for Crude Oil is `=googlefinance ("WTI")` as shown in the below example

[image]

This was borne out by the result below achieved at the same time from [https://www.google.com/finance/quote/WTI:NYSE`](https://www.google.com/finance/quote/WTI:NYSE%60)

The web page constantly updates so be aware that results change dynamically and it may be necessary to refresh the sheet accordingly.

[image]

Comment: Hey 24601, thank you for the reply. I think I tried that too but WTI is the price for the company though not for crude oil